# Enum with attribute vs class with properties

Tags: c#, enums

I'm working on an application and I'm wondering wether I should use an `Enum` with a `StringValueAttribute` vs a `class` with properties.

My first approach is `Enum` with a `StringValueAttribute`. This is the approach I'm using now. Through a method called `GetStringValue()` I'm able to get the resource value.

```
public enum Icon
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The NoruBox contains a symbol consisting of a cardboard box.
    /// </summary>
    [StringValue("/Noru;Component/NoruBox/Media/Box_512.png")]
    Box = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// The NoruBox contains a symbol consisting of a bust.
    /// </summary>
    [StringValue("/Noru;Component/NoruBox/Media/Person_512.png")]
    Person = 1,

    // More values (total of 5).
}
```

The alternative approach would be a `class` with properties of the type `Icon` (which would have a **Name** and a **Resource** property. This would also give me the option to add a `GetAll()` method that returns a list with all the available icons.

```
public static class Icons
{
    public static List<Icon> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<Icon> { Box, Person, ... };
    }

    public static Icon Box = new Continent("Box", Localizer.GetString("/Noru;Component/NoruBox/Media/Box_512.png"));
    public static Icon Person = new Continent("Person", Localizer.GetString("/Noru;Component/NoruBox/Media/Person_512.png"));
    // More Icons (total of 5).
}
```

Which one of both would be the best approach and why? Right now, (though I'm using the Enums) the class approach looks a lot cleaner in code than with the Enum. With the Enum I have to type for example `_icon.GetStringValue()` vs `_icon.Resource` with the class.

**EDIT1:** A little more clarification: The `Icon` can be compared with one of the `MessageBox` except for having an extra resource reference in my project.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `xml` or `json`, you shouldnt really be using C# `class`es or files for data- saving

Comment: @Andrew: The icon has to be used while writing the application. Like the `Icon` of a `MessageBox`. (Added this to the original post.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach would be to use an enum with extension methods for each of the additional properties you want to associate with the items in the enum.  Consider the following:

```
public static class IconInfo
{
    public static string FileName(this Icon icon)
    {
        switch (icon)
        {
            case Icon.Box: return "/Noru;Component/NoruBox/Media/Box_512.png";
            case Icon.Person: return "/Noru;Component/NoruBox/Media/Person_512.png";
            default: return "";
        }
    }
}

public enum Icon
{
    Box = 0,
    Person = 1,
}
```

You could then iterate over "All" of the values similar to the following:

```
        foreach (Icon icon in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Icon)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", icon, icon.FileName()));
        }
```

You will need to decide whether to return a default value or throw an exception if an invalid value is passed to one of your extension methods.

Comment: IMHO, this would be the overall fastest approach (not only regarding icon retrieval); the only other alternative I see is storing **icon paths** into a static array accessed by index using the `Icon` underlying integer values. The only downside is that `Icon` members and **icon paths** are hardcoded.

Comment: @Lorek: This looks like a very nice and clean approach. I'm still considering the `class` approach 'cause of Hakam Fostok's answer.

Comment: @Rubidium37: Why are hardcoded paths so bad? The icons have a assembly path that will probably never change, only added to. Also, the `MessageBox` must have hardcoded icons somewhere or am I wrong?

Comment: They are not bad, but hardcoded info is fine when you know in advance any possible optional, reason why enums are usually the best choice and the approach by @lorek fits very well.

Answer (score 1):

1- Consider that using the attributes will decrease the performance because you need to make reflection of the Enum values to get the string value (this will cost)
if the Performance is important in your application you can use the class way.

2- in other hand , the using of the class could give you more flexibility, May be in the later time you will add someThing to the Icon (for example the size of it)
in this point also the class win.

3- I think that the using of the Classes will make the code more clean and readable over the using of the Enum.

4- From (design point of view) the Icon could be considered as an class (according to the specification of your application). if you are concentrating of the Icon in your application, then It could be better to use class.